# What is causing this Heroku mysql connection error? (Trying to connect frontend to backend POST request)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku

{Solved}. New Bug

Error from Heroku logs:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236657+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect.          [as        oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16) {
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236658+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236658+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236658+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236659+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236659+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2021-09-23T18:24:12.236659+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
```

---

Information / Background:

React js front end (hosted now on Netlifty)
Javascript Node backend using Express and MYSQL2 (Hosted on Heroku)

Goal:
To connect Neflifty Frontend POST request with Heroku Backend fetching POST payload data and inserting it into MYSQL table.

Update: 09/24/2021

I have done all that was suggested.  I have created a new database with clearDB.  Added it and tested the connection in mysql Workbench.  Created the table needed.  Updated the backend code for creating the connection to the new database.  Checked heroko variables and made sure they reflected correctly to the new database.  Now there is an authorization issue.  {solved}

New Backend Code with corrections:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.Port || 8000

app.listen(port);
console.log(`server is listing on ${port}`);
```

Time Out

[image]

Question:
If this connects locally on workbench why wouldn't Heroku connect if they are added as variables?   {Answered}

New question:
why is it trying to use port 8000 when it should be using the environment? Why is it timing out?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which database add-on are you using on Heroku?

Comment: @JoãoFernandes I am not using any database addons.  I am using  Heroku CLI.   To deploy this I simply push the code with  git push heroku main .  After that when opening the app it then runs the node javascript seen above.  That is when I check the logs.   If there is an easier way of running the server.js file through one of Heroku's addon's I woule be interested in knowing that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to the database because you don't have any database instance running at Heroku. Once you pushed your code using Heroku CLI, Heroku sets up a NodeJS application for you, but it does not mean that it will set up a database for you aswell.

You can add a database to your app through Heroku's interface or CLI. From CLI (we are going to setup ClearDB but any MySQL database addon may work):

```
heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
```

After done that, you wanna have your new database URL (which won't be localhost) with:

```
heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
```

The last command's output will be something like:

```
mysql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<database>?reconnect=true
```

Now, with this in hand, you shall modify your code a little bit with that new information. You don't want to expose your database credentials in your versioning control, so you may use environment variables to get it done:

```js
const db =  mysql.createConnection({
    connectionaLimit: 50,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    port: 3306
});
```

Also, you need to set the environment variables for your running Heroku's app:

```
heroku config:set DB_USER=<user>
heroku config:set DB_PASSWORD=<password>
heroku config:set DB_HOST=<host>
heroku config:set DATABASE=<database>
```

Now, you have a database instance running at Heroku and a NodeJS app instance running that can connect to this database.

For further reading, you may wanna take a look at those links:

https://lo-victoria.com/build-a-mysql-nodejs-crud-app-4-deploying-to-heroku-finale

https://www.bezkoder.com/deploy-node-js-app-heroku-cleardb-mysql/

https://raddy.co.uk/blog/how-to-deploy-node-js-express-ejs-mysql-website-on-heroku-cleardb/ (this one uses Heroku's interface)

Comment: Fernandes :  Thanks for this well-explained answer.  I have also looked at the links you provided and they were also very helpful.   I have done all that you suggested and created a new database in mysql workbench.  For reasons unknown to me, I am getting an access denied error.    Any more assistance on this would be nice.  I updated the post with more information and screen shots and updated code.

Comment: @benholsinger remove your `?reconnect=true` from your `DATABASE` env var. Careful about sharing your credentials! Anyone who sees your post can access your Heroku database now. If I were you, I would remove this add-on and re-add to Heroku to renew your credentials :)

Comment: @Fernandes Thanks and that is good advice.  The connections work now.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Ferandes thanks again for your help.  I have one more concern if you have some more time to spare.     When I look at the logs again it appears it times out when trying to bind the port.  I have made sure I have : app.listen (app is express) set to process.env.Port || 8000. All resources seem to validate how that is set.     In the logs this happens: heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=fwd="65.144.6.34" 
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Comment: @benholsinger environment variables are case sensitive. Just change to uppercase: `process.env.PORT`. If this answer solves your problem, would you mind marking it as accepted answer?

Comment: please more clean answer , i didnt understand because i cant full speak in english . my question is ... so we must add addons to heroku to connect ***my own server database*** ?